# Why do these objects all have the same date?

Tags: javascript

I don't seem to understand why all the foo.dates are the same value. I was expecting it to increase by one day for each iteration.

If anyone could explain why and a possible solution that would be nice :)

Thank you.

```
Date.prototype.nextDay=function()
{
    this.setDate(this.getDate()+1);
    return this;
}

aDate = new Date(0);

function foo()
{
    this.date = aDate.nextDay();
}

ary = new Array();
for (i=1;i<5;i++){    
    ary.push(new foo());
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(ary, null, 4));
```

Foo Objects:

```
[
    {
        "date": "1970-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date": "1970-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date": "1970-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    {
        "date": "1970-01-05T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
]
```

Comment: weiredest javascript code I have seen in a long time. One should never call a function with `new`.

Comment: @Christoph Why not? That's how you make objects according to  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: You have chosen the worst possible source you can consult when trying to learn Javascript ([why?](http://w3fools.com/)). Go to [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/), [Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/) or some other reliable source to learn Javascript.

Comment: I didn't know that :D, I actually thought it was a W3C site. But https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain also suggest what I'm doing (With a constructor) so it's not "bad" :)

Comment: It looks like you are coming from a language which has class-based inheritance. Javascript is different. Yes, you can create new Objects with the `new` Constructor but usually that's not the way how you would work in Javascript. http://www.crockford.com/javascript/inheritance.html, http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a read and yes I do write OOP most of the time :)

Comment: @Christoph Nothing wrong with using `new`, that's just silly advice. That's how you create new objects in Javascript, period. If you want some fancy inheritance or private variables, sure use whatever but that would be unneeded here and has nothing to do with the appropriateness of `new`.

Comment: @yaku I didn't say that it's wrong to use `new` in general. It just makes absolutely no sense in the usecase provided by the OP. Why alter a native prototype (without protection!) and use a lot of objects where a simple function call would completely suffice? Your proclaimed appropriateness of `new` is not given for this case. Also most people coming from other languages think that `this.` properties are private which is simply not the case.

Comment: @Christoph Fair enough :) I'm assuming the code here is example code out of context, and that there is some reason it's done like that in this case.

Comment: @yaku I can recommend Stefanov's [JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do) for good Javascript Patterns including inheritance and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because aDate is referred to in the foo function, and `this.date = aDate.nextDay()` *doesn't clone it*. It just creates a new reference to the same object.

So you are using the same instance of date (adate) for all foo instances.

You don't need to change the prototype of Date or to use new, if you want a increment since Jan 1 1970 then this function would work :-

```
var nextDate = (function() {
  var days = 0;
  return function() {
    var date = new Date(0);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + ++days);
    return date;
  }
})();
```

nextDate(); //Fri Jan 02 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

nextDate(); //Sat Jan 03 1970 01:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)

If you want the first call to nextDate to give Jan 1 then change ++days to days++

Comment: I see, so it's just a pointer to aDate. Is there a way to make it evaluate or is there a better way?

Comment: You need to clone the aDate in the foo method this.date =  new Date(aDate.nextDay());